# SSRS report - pivoting data (last columns grouping)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to achieve the attached prototype for ssrs report.  I was able to get all the data but can not figure out how to show the last three columns ("First Time Posted", "Last Time Cancelled" and "Total Duration")

When i try with expression it show data for every single corresponding line, just want to show one entry based on group.

Thank you,

Desired output
[image]

Report design

[image]

Data will be like

```
| Cp Label | Time Posted | Time Cancelled| Duration | Link ID|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cp 1     | 12:56:00    | 12:57:05      | 00:01:05 |  1     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cp 2     | 12:57:05    | 1:00:00       | 00:02:55 |  1     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cp 3     | 12:57:00    | 1:15:00       | 00:18:00 |  2     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You need to add more info. **edit** your question to show the report design including rowgroups, columngroups and their configuration. Also show the structure of your sample data as it looks in your dataset.

Comment: As @AlanSchofield has said, you need to add more info.

Comment: @AlanSchofield updated the query. hope i addressed your questions

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V updated info.

Comment: What columns does your rowgroup group by?

Comment: @AlanSchofield  there is no row grouping. just sort by link id and time posted.

Comment: your `EventGroup` rowgroup looks like it does having grouping, double-click it and check. If there was no grouping it would show as a details group with 3 lines in the icon to the left of the name.

Comment: @AlanSchofield i checked and its fine. I am just stuck with  last right three columns. how to show single row(box) for multiple rows on the left.